# Displaying a list of items that are stored on shared preferences

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences

I have a recyclerview with a couple of items. When someone clicks on an item in the Main Fragment, it is stored on sharedpreferences and then all clicked items are supposed to be displayed on another fragment. My issue is when someone clicks on an item, only the first clicked item is displayed on the other fragment(Details Fragment) instead of a list of items.

These are the methods of saving, retrieving and removing items on my SessionManager.class

```
public void saveitems(Context context,List<SingleItem> items){

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String cartitems = gson.toJson(items);
        editor.putString(KEY_ITEMS,cartitems);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void grandtotal (String total){
        editor.putString(KEY_TOTAL,total);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void savetocart(Context context, SingleItem singleitems){
        List<SingleItem>  itemList = getItems(context);

        if (itemList == null) {

                itemList = new ArrayList<>();
                itemList.add(singleitems);
                saveitems(context, itemList);

        }

    }

    public ArrayList<SingleItem>  getItems(Context context){
        List<SingleItem> items;

        if (pref.contains(KEY_ITEMS)){
            String cartitems = pref.getString(KEY_ITEMS,null);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            SingleItem[] singleItems = gson.fromJson(cartitems,SingleItem[].class);

            items = Arrays.asList(singleItems);
            items = new ArrayList<>(items);

        }
        else
            return null;

        return (ArrayList<SingleItem>) items;
    }

    public void removeitem(Context context, SingleItem singleItem){
        ArrayList<SingleItem> items = getItems(context);

        if (items != null){
            items.remove(singleItem);
            saveitems(context,items);
        }
    }
```

This is how i am storing the items that have been clicked. Take a look at (RecyclerItems):

```
package com.carlton.shop;


import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import es.dmoral.toasty.Toasty;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import ss.com.bannerslider.banners.RemoteBanner;
import ss.com.bannerslider.views.BannerSlider;



/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    private BannerSlider bannerSlider;
    private RecyclerView Categories;
    public RecyclerView RecyclerItems;
    private ShopItemAdapter adapter;
    private List<ShopItem> item;
    SessionManager sessionManager;
    private List<SingleItem> items;
    private SingleItemAdapter adapters;
    private LinearLayout Layoutcategories, Layoutitems;
    private TextView CatName;
    private Button Up;


    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        bannerSlider = (BannerSlider) view.findViewById(R.id.banner_slider1);
        Categories = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclercategories);
        Layoutcategories = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.LayoutCategories);
        Layoutitems = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.LayoutItems);
        RecyclerItems = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycleritems);
        CatName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvcategoryname);
        Up = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnup);

        sessionManager = new SessionManager(getContext());

        Categories.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        Categories.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        RecyclerItems.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        RecyclerItems.setLayoutManager(layoutmanager);

        Categories.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getContext(), new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

                Layoutcategories.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Layoutitems.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                sessionManager.createcategorysession(item.get(position).getCategory());
                HashMap<String, String> cat = sessionManager.getcategoryitems();

                CatName.setText(cat.get(SessionManager.KEY_CATEGORY));

                Up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Layoutitems.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Layoutcategories.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });


                items = new ArrayList<>(item.get(position).getItems());
                adapters = new SingleItemAdapter(getContext(),items);
                RecyclerItems.setAdapter(adapters);
                RecyclerItems.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getContext(), new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                            sessionManager.savetocart(getContext(), items.get(position));
                            Toasty.success(getContext(),"Added to cart",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,true).show();


                    }

                }));

            }
        }));


        Banner();

        getdata();

        return view;
    }


    private void Banner() {
        bannerSlider.addBanner(new RemoteBanner("http://supa.swagshop.co.ke/Images/moto.png"));
        bannerSlider.addBanner(new RemoteBanner("http://supa.swagshop.co.ke/Images/moto.png"));
        bannerSlider.addBanner(new RemoteBanner("http://supa.swagshop.co.ke/Images/moto.png"));
        bannerSlider.addBanner(new RemoteBanner("http://supa.swagshop.co.ke/Images/moto.png"));

    }


    private void getdata() {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Items...");
        progressDialog.show();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        InterfaceRequest request = retrofit.create(InterfaceRequest.class);
        Call<JSONResponse> call =request.getJSON();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()){

                    JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();

                    item = new ArrayList<>(jsonResponse.getItem());
                    adapter = new ShopItemAdapter(getContext(),item);
                    Categories.setAdapter(adapter);

                } else {
                    Toasty.warning(getContext(),"Oops! Items could not be loaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,true).show();
                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toasty.error(getContext(),t.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,true).show();
                Log.d(Constants.TAG,t.getMessage());
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

        });

    }

}
```

This is how i'm retrieving the items on DetailsFragment;

```
package com.carlton.shop;


import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import es.dmoral.toasty.Toasty;

import static com.helpshift.util.HelpshiftContext.getApplicationContext;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Details extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView RecyclerDetails;
    private TextView CartPrice;
    private CheckBox CheckCart;

    private List<SingleItem> list;
    private CartAdapter adapter;
    private boolean add = false;
    private Paint p = new Paint();
    private SessionManager sessionManager;



    public Details() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false);

        RecyclerDetails = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclercart);
        CartPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvcart);
        CheckCart = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkcart);

        sessionManager = new SessionManager(getContext());

        RecyclerDetails.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        RecyclerDetails.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        list = sessionManager.getItems(getContext());

        RecyclerDetails.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getContext(), new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }
        }));



        if(list != null){
            Toasty.info(getContext(),"Swipe to go to Next", Toast.LENGTH_LONG,true).show();
            adapter = new CartAdapter(getContext(),list);
            RecyclerDetails.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

        //initswipe();
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your session manager something's not right with the `savetocart()` method.

The first time it called, `getItems()` will return null as expected, therefore the **if** statement in the next line will resolve to **true** and an item will be added. But after that `itemList` will not be null, therefore the **if** statement will always resolve to **false** and no items are added to the list.

That method should look like this

```
public void savetocart(Context context, SingleItem singleitems){
    List<SingleItem>  itemList = getItems(context);

    if (itemList == null) {
       itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    itemList.add(singleitems);
    saveitems(context, itemList);

}
```